# FDT / Eclipse : path variable

Tags: eclipse, fdt, path-variables

I am trying to create a script that would list all the linked libraries in an FDT project and their corresponding svn repositories.

My problem : I was not able to find the file on my system where Eclipse (or FDT, I'm not even sure) writes all of the path variables.

I have tried capturing changes on my system and have had no luck.

If anyone knows where to find this file (Mac OS X) or knows a technique I could use to find it, it would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FDT, you can find the list linked libraries in the .as3_classpath file if those libraries are in your project folder (or below). They reflect the content you add in the 'Library' tab of 'FDT Build Path' in your project's properties. There's also an entry in the .project file that reflect the linked libraries you add with the 'Source' tab. Those libraries can be located anywhere on your hard drive, and that's why you define 'path variables' for them.

Personally, I create a 'lib' folder in my project where I copy the libraries I need and add them with the 'Library' tab. I find it much easier to share the project (since everything is relative to the project) and you don't need to worry about having two projects modifying the same library file.

For the location of those 'Path' variables, as far as I know, could only be located in your eclipse installation folder or in your eclipse 'settings' folder, usually in your 'user' directory.

Comment: I already knew most of what you say, but your technique of sharing libraries might actually be an alternative to this whole script thing. It would be much less fun though...

Comment: Revisiting my old questions, I noticed I never accepted this answer although I've been using this approach ever since.

Here's your late reputation boost subb...